# How to make random image generator with percent?

Tags: javascript, html

First i am so sorry about my bad english .
I wanna ask how to make this script , i want to put the percents ? I mean every image  to have their percent like um a image1 to have 5% to show up image 2 to have 10% to show up and like that?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input class="randombutton" type="button" value="Randomize" onclick="randomImg1()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function randomImg1() {


      myImages1 = new Array();
      myImages1[0] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[1] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[2] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[3] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[4] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[5] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[6] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[7] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[8] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[9] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[10] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[11] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[12] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[13] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[14] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[15] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[16] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[17] = "images/2.gif";
   myImages1[18] = "images/1.gif";
      myImages1[19] = "images/2.gif";

      var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * myImages1.length ); //incorporated other solution

      document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image'></img>";
    }

</script>
<div id="image"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You had php tag. Dammit, I could do this easily if it was php.

Comment: Hi if this any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Make an array that holds precent individually for each picture.
That means you have myImages1 which is an array that have in each cell image.
each cell has a number.
you make another array called precent that on its cell number it holds precent for image in the other array in the same cell number.

```
function randomImg1() {

  var precent = new Array();
  myImages1 = new Array();
  myImages1[0] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[0] = 5;
  myImages1[1] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[1] = 10;
  myImages1[2] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[2] = 20;
  myImages1[3] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[3] = 30;
  myImages1[4] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[4] = 40;
  myImages1[5] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[5] = 70;
  myImages1[6] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[6] = 90;
  myImages1[7] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[7] = 45;
  myImages1[8] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[8] = 93;
  myImages1[9] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[9] = 21;
  myImages1[10] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[10] = 20;
  myImages1[11] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[11] = 34;
  myImages1[12] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[12] = 66;
  myImages1[13] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[13] = 94;
  myImages1[14] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[14] = 56;
  myImages1[15] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[15] = 87;
  myImages1[16] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[16] = 12;
  myImages1[17] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[17] = 44;
  myImages1[18] = "images/1.gif";
  precent[18] = 76;
  myImages1[19] = "images/2.gif";
  precent[19] = 89;

  var rnd = Math.floor( Math.random() * myImages1.length ); //incorporated other solution

   document.getElementById("image").innerHTML = "<img src='" + myImages1[rnd] + "' alt='image' width='"+precent[rnd]+"%' height='"+precent[rnd]+"%'></img>";

}
```

Change the precentage for every picture as you like.

Comment: I cant understand ? can you put it in my code please if you can?

Comment: You change your document.getElementById with my line of code and the code above you need to assign precentage for each of the pictures, Like for picture at myImages1[5] you do precent[5] = 5; - it will give it 5 precent size